# Subtract 2 strings in Java equals null

Tags: java

In C, if I subtract a `string` from the same `string`, it will result in `NULL`.
So, if `str1 = str2`  ,  `str1 = str2 - str1 = NULL`.
How do I achieve the same null operation/result in Java?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot substract strings mathematically. Java **IS NOT** C. Please explain what you're trying to do and the proper code to replicate the issue.

Comment: You can't; for one you can't substract strings.

Answer (score 5):

You can't subtract strings in C or Java.

**In C,** you can subtract two *addresses* of strings. If they're the same address, you'll get zero. If they're not the same address, you'll get a meaningful result only if they're in the same block of allocated memory.

You can get a nonzero result from the subtraction of the addresses of two equal strings stored in different memory locations. You can test C string equality with `strcmp` or `strncmp()`. (The latter should be preferred.)

**In Java,** if you want to determine if two strings are the **same object**, you can use the equality operator. For example, `str1 == str2` will return true if the two are the same object.

If you want to determine if the two strings are **equal**, you can use the `equals()` method. For example, `str1.equals( str2 )` will return true if the two strings are equal. If either might be null, you can use instead `Objects.equals( str1, str2 )`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way of doing that in java, because you cannot use "-" operator on objects. Only if your objective is put null when both objects are equals, you can achieve the null result as follows:

```
    String str1 = "hola";
    String str2 = "hola";
    String str3 = "";

    if(str1.equals(str2)){
        str3 = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Actually, no. Subtracting same pointers should not necessarily result in `NULL`.** What it will surely be is zero, of type `ptrdiff_t`. `NULL` being zero is an assumption not guaranteed to be valid.

But this doesn't work in Java at all since it doesn't have pointers (not as primitive types) and, subsequently, pointer arithmetic; strings are known by their references. You can't do too much with Java's references apart from dereferencing them (and a reference is guaranteed to succeed unless it's `null`), assigning and comparing them for equality. That's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

In C your string variables are pointers, which are numeric, and you can perform subtraction on them.

In Java your string variables are references to **String** objects and attempting subtraction is a type error.  Specifically **-** is limited to use on specific primitive numeric types: **byte**, **short**, **int**, **long**, **float**, and **double**.

To determine if two **String** variables reference the same object in memory you would use **str1 == str2** (double-equals) which determines reference equality.  To determine if two **String** variables have the same value (but may be distinct references) you would use **str1.equals(str2)** assuming **str1 != null**.